# Tic Tac Toe on Android

Tags: java, android, tic-tac-toe

Can someone review my Tic Tac Toe Code? I tried to make it as compact as I could. What could I improve?

I save the state of the buttons by adding `freezesText="true"` in the XML file. This is for saving the state on orientation change.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button[][] buttons = new Button[3][3];

    private boolean player1Turn = true;

    private int player1Points;
    private int player2Points;

    private TextView textViewPlayer1;
    private TextView textViewPlayer2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textViewPlayer1 = findViewById(R.id.text_view_p1);
        textViewPlayer2 = findViewById(R.id.text_view_p2);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                String buttonID = "button_" + i + j;
                int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id", getPackageName());
                buttons[i][j] = findViewById(resID);
                buttons[i][j].setOnClickListener(this);
            }
        }

        Button buttonReset = findViewById(R.id.button_reset);
        buttonReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                resetGame();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (!((Button) v).getText().equals("")) {
            return;
        }

        if (player1Turn) {
            ((Button) v).setText("X");
        } else {
            ((Button) v).setText("O");
        }

        if (checkForWin()) {
            if (player1Turn) {
                player1wins();
            } else {
                player2wins();
            }
            updatePointsText();
            startNewGame();
        }

        player1Turn = !player1Turn;

    }


    private boolean checkForWin() {
        String[][] results = new String[3][3];

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                results[i][j] = buttons[i][j].getText().toString();
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            Log.d("check", "checkForWin: Starting if 1");
            if (results[i][0].equals(results[i][1])
                    && results[i][0].equals(results[i][2])
                    && !results[i][0].equals("")) {
                return true;
            }
            Log.d("check", "checkForWin: Starting if 2");
            if (results[0][i].equals(results[1][i])
                    && results[0][i].equals(results[2][i])
                    && !results[0][i].equals("")) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        if (results[0][0].equals(results[1][1])
                && results[0][0].equals(results[2][2])
                && !results[0][0].equals("")) {
            return true;
        }

        if (results[0][2].equals(results[1][1])
                && results[0][2].equals(results[2][0])
                && !results[0][2].equals("")) {
            return true;
        }

        boolean emptyFieldLeft = false;

        outer:
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                //  Log.d("loop", "Looping through: " + i + " " + j);
                if (results[i][j].equals("")) {
                    emptyFieldLeft = true;
                    break outer;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!emptyFieldLeft) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Draw!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startNewGame();
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void player1wins() {
        player1Points++;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Player 1 wins!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private void player2wins() {
        player2Points++;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Player 2 wins!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private void updatePointsText() {
        textViewPlayer1.setText("Player 1: " + player1Points);
        textViewPlayer2.setText("Player 2: " + player2Points);
    }

    private void startNewGame() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                buttons[i][j].setText("");
            }
        }
    }

    private void resetGame() {
        player1Points = 0;
        player2Points = 0;
        updatePointsText();
        startNewGame();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putInt("player1Points", player1Points);
        outState.putInt("player2Points", player2Points);
        outState.putBoolean("player1Turn", player1Turn);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        player1Points = savedInstanceState.getInt("player1Points");
        player2Points = savedInstanceState.getInt("player2Points");
        player1Turn = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("player1Turn");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for sharing your code.

## Naming

Finding good names is the hardest part in programming, so always take your time to think about the names of your identifiers.

#### Choose you names from the problem domain, not from the technical solution.

You have names like `buttons` which are taken from the *implementation details*. You should rather choose names more connected to your *business case* e.g.: this variable could be named: `gameCells`.

#### Naming Conventions

Please read (and follow) the Java Naming Conventions.
E.g: you have methods like `player1wins()` and `player2wins()`. But methods should start woith a *verb* so better names would be like `reportWinPlayer1()`

## Magic numbers

your code has some magic numbers. This are literal values with a special meaning like here:

> ```
>     for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
>         for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
> ```

You should either use *constants* with meaningful names like

```
private static final int GAME_FIELD_SIZE =3;
// ...
    for (int i = 0; i < GAME_FIELD_SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < GAME_FIELD_SIZE; j++) {
```

or use existing constraints like so:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < buttons[0].length; j++) {
```

The string literal `""` is a *magic number* too. So you should use a *constant* here too:

```
private static final String EMPTY_FIELD = "";
//
if (results[i][j].equals(EMPTY_FIELD)) {
```

## Avoid `break` or `continue` especially when used with labels

`break` and `continue` are *the poor mans `goto`*. Code using them is hard to follow and even harder to *refactor* (that is: improving the codes *design* without changing its *behavior*).

## Single Responsibility/Separation of Concerns

In your excample you mix business logic with user interaction like this:

> ```
> // in `checkForWin()`
>     if (!emptyFieldLeft) {
>         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Draw!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
> ```

also this method immediately calls  `startNewGame()` which is somehow surprising in a method with the name `checkForWin`. Both (and most likely the surrounding `if` should not be located somewhere else.

## Code duplication

Your approach has lots of code which is almost the same except some constant values like this:

> ```
>     if (results[0][0].equals(results[1][1])
>             && results[0][0].equals(results[2][2])
>             && !results[0][0].equals("")) {
>         return true;
>     }
>
>     if (results[0][2].equals(results[1][1])
>             && results[0][2].equals(results[2][0])
>             && !results[0][2].equals("")) {
>         return true;
>     }
> ```

You could make it being *the same* by introducing a *variable* for the constant differing:

```
    int columnIndex=0;
    if (results[0][columnIndex].equals(results[1][1])
            && results[0][columnIndex].equals(results[2][2])
            && !results[0][columnIndex].equals("")) {
        return true;
    }
    columnIndex=2;
    if () {
        return true;
    }
```

Now you have *identical* code which you can *extract* to a *parameterized* using your IDE's automated refactoring:

```
  private boolean isOwnedCompleteColumn(int columnIndex){
       return results[0][columnIndex].equals(results[1][1])
            && results[0][columnIndex].equals(results[2][2-columnIndex])
            && !results[0][columnIndex].equals("");
  }
```

and the duplicated part changes to

```
    if (isOwnedCompleteColumn(0)) {
        return true;
    }

    if (isOwnedCompleteColumn(2)) {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I will take a bit time and try to implement everything.

Comment: What do you think about me saving the Button texts into a String each time i check for the winner, like i do in my example? Is that too inefficient?

Comment: @FlorianWalther You should learn about the MVC / MVVM pattern. This basically says that you hold the *state* in some *model classes* and have your *business logic* working on them. The *view* (which is your buttons) only displays the current content (aka state) of the model and triggers the business logic.

Comment: Is there also a name for the way it i do it?
And why are most tutorials built like my approach? I often hear about these design patterns but then i usualy see the code the way i wrote it. Is it more used for real apps with more complexity?

Comment: @FlorianWalther *"Is there also a name for the way it i do it?"* You mean apart from "wrong"? **;o)** Only *mixing layers* comes to my mind...